# Cannot resolve symbol Services when using Configuration.Services.GetContentNegotiator()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I wanted to retrieve conneg by using following line of code.

```
Configuration.Services.GetContentNegotiator
```

It gives me an error "Cannot resolve symbol Services".  I am building ASP.NET Web API using ASP.NET MVC 4.  Services is a public property of System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration but I can't get a reference of that object.

Comment: it's part of RC, so it has to be resolved as long as you have a using statement for System.Web.Http. Can you attach a sample project? or maybe try doing this from an empty template - perhaps you are still referencing BETA dlls

Comment: Thanks Filip. How can I check if I am using BETA or RC?

Comment: Fire up your Web API application, connect the VS debugger, go to Debug > Windows > Modules and check the version of System.Web.Http.dll
It should be from 5/5/2012. See screenshot http://screencast.com/t/XY4lpQVhVDgq